# Is possible with Castle Windsor Interceptor to intercept only a specific method in a class and ignore the other ones?

Tags: castle-windsor, interceptor

Dears,
I have an interface **IJob** that has a method called **ExecuteAsync** and i want to intercept this method **only** but my derived classes may have many methods and i found the interceptor intercept them also.
My question is, 
Is this possible with Castle Windsor
and this is my registration

```
iocManager.IocContainer.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (key, handler) =>
        {
            var implementationType = handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.GetTypeInfo();
            if(ShouldIntercept(implementationType))
            {
                handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(AuthenticateJobInterceptor)));
            }
        };

private static bool ShouldIntercept(Type type)
    {
        if (typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. There's a `IProxyGenerationHook` interface that you can implement to control what gets intercepted. [The tutorial I wrote a decade ago](http://kozmic.net/2009/01/17/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-iii-selecting-which-methods-to/) still (for better or worse) seems to be the best resource about it.

There's a couple ways to set it up in Windsor.

Ideally, if possible, you'd do it during registration, in your `IWindsorInstaller`:

```
var yourHook = new YourHook();
container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
      .BasedOn<IJob>()
      .LifestyleTransient()
      .WithServiceBase()
      .Configure(c =>
         c.Interceptors<AuthenticateJobInterceptor>()       
          .Proxy.Hook(yourHook)));
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code similar to what it is now (I'd recommend wrapping in a [ComponentModel construction contributor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/componentmodel-construction-contributors.md)), you can do something like:

```
var options = handler.ComponentModel.ObtainProxyOptions();
options.Hook = yourHook; // InstanceReference(yourHook)
```